# User to User Database Object Structure

Tags: database, express, mongoose, mean-stack

What is the best practice to structure my objects in my database in a Teacher to Student application? To be more specific, a teacher will have multiple students, and students may have multiple teachers they will interact with. Right now, each class a teacher is instructing has a "class id" and when a student enrolls, they add that same class ID to a list in their model. When a teacher wants to view a roster, I use

```
Student.find({"class-id": "abc123"}, function(err, student){
    if(err){
       console.log(err)
    } else {
       res.render("/roster", {student: student});
    }
 });
```

"abc123" is an example class code.

It's very basic code at the moment-- just starting a rough app. Should I make some type of different database structure with some type of hierarchy between teachers and students?

Sorry for the basic and perhaps confusing question, I'm very new to web development and just don't want to paint myself into a corner.

I'm using the MEAN stack but I think this is a more conceptual question.

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like your data model is relational. Are you sure you want to be using MongoDB?

Comment: @dmfay I suppose a relational database would suit me better considering there's going to significant data entry and it isn't going to need to be very flexible. However, Mongoose is all I know at this point- certainly willing to learn MySQL and do some research on different data models. Thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dmfay's comment is insightful. with a relational model, using mongoose is suboptimal. However, you of course can still use it. it would go something like this (by the way, you were unclear about this, but its implied that each student and teacher have multiple class-ids, im working under that assumption)

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var StudentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    //other student details
    teachers: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Teacher"
    }],
    classIds: [STRING]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Student", StudentSchema);
```

and then the teacher schema would be along the same lines:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var TeacherSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    //other teacher details
    students: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Student"
    }],
    classIds: [STRING]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Teacher", TeacherSchema);
```

then, how you go about it is, when a student enrols for a class, you find all teachers with that classId in their classIds array, you loop over them adding the student to each one of their students array, and you add them (the teacher) to the student's teachers array.

when you want to search for all students in a class, you go about like you did, except that the classIds is an array of strings, not a single string, you need to check if any of them matches

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I ended up doing.

Comment: when you get a correct answer on stackoverflow, mark it correct, and if you'd like upvote it. this is important so 1) users browsing through questions know you already got your answer and don't waste time trying to help only to realise the question is already answered. 2) so if somebody has a similar problem they know there is an answer here and don't end up creating duplicates